# Solr/Siren - Insert/Index data using sparql

Tags: solr, sparql, siren

I am using [siren](/questions/tagged/siren) in my application that interacts with [solr](/questions/tagged/solr). I know how to index data into Solr(/solr/update),but I can't figure out how to index using siren. Does it even support indexing? Also, can we use sparql queries to index data in Solr?

Comment: bro did you figure out a way to index arbitrary json document using the "siren/add" handler? I am able to achieve the same using the *post.jar* which gets built along with the project.

Answer (score 1):

Yes SIREn is able to index RDF data. If I remember well, within the download bundle there's a README with detailed instructions. Also, there should be a test case that illustrates how to index / query in a programmatic way.

About your second question: the answer is no: as SIREn indexes "entities" you're not able to execute plain SPARQL queries (but you have a lot of other capabilities)

As a side note, let me suggest you this  project [1] which is another kind of approach for indexing RDF data using Solr. There, you can run SPARQL queries and have some other interesting features like faceting. The overall project is still in progress (especially the mix between the RDF and Solr world) but main features (sparql, some kind of faceting, sparql results pagination) are already working.

In my blog [2] you can find several post about this project.

---

[1] https://github.com/agazzarini/SolRDF.
[2] https://andreagazzarini.blogspot.com

Comment: Does SIREn supports SPARQL queries?

Comment: I don't think. SIREn doesn't manage triples as units but instead it indexes (and therefore manages) entities (i.e. the RDF representation of entities). I say "I don't think" because this is how SIREn worked two years ago. Since the E of SIREn means "Entities" I think things are still working in that way

Comment: How do we index data in siren? For ex., if i call the url - ..siren/update, it actually calls Solr's update handler. And therefore sending rdf document on this url is useless. Do we have any other mechanism in siren to index? Or maybe any other url to handle this?

Comment: Sorry I had a look at the project in GitHub, and I must say that is different from the SIREn I knew...previously there was a dedicated request handler for managing RDF data. Now I'm not able to find it so I think it's better to join the SIREn mailing list (https://groups.google.com/d/forum/siren-user) and ask there your question